# How to tell RadioButtonList to NOT generate a table

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

When I set up a RadioButtonList it creates a table layout for it and I don't want this... how do I get rid of it?

*It might be a duplicate but I've searched and haven't manage to find a question like this here.*

Comment: Microsoft have made some bad decisions in their time, but putting *everything* in ASP.NET into a table for layout ... What can I say!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You'll have to change the `RepeatLayout` property and setting it to `Flow` will probably yield the result you are searching for.

Take a look at all the other `RepeatLayout` options here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatlayout.aspx

Kinda silly the 4.0 framework still defaults the ugly table variant, I mostly revert to the `UnorderedList` variant.

Comment: i find myself looking for this thread every few weeks. glad it's still here.

Comment: It is a awesome question and answer, i work on ASP.NET 10 years and never know that.